# Typescript construct a sub-dictionnary from dictionnary and list of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary

I am trying to create a sub-dictionary from a dictionary and a list of keys.

```js
type MyDictElementType = {
  x: number
}
type MyDictType = {
  [key: string]: MyDictElementType
}

const myKeys: string[] = ['a']
const myDict: MyDictType = { 'a': {x: 0}, 'b': {x: 1} }

const createSubDictionary = (fullDictionary: MyDictType, searchKeys: string[]) => {
  const newDict: MyDictType = {}
  searchKeys.map((searchKey) => {
    newDict[searchKey] = fullDictionary[searchKey]
  })
  return newDict
}
```

Is there a pure functional way to achieve that without the `newDict` local variable ?

Comment: Something like this? https://tsplay.dev/WKkXgW it mutates the original object so it isn't purely functional

Comment: @Christian thanks for your answer. Not what I'm looking for indeed, it mutates the original object.

Comment: What is your goal here?  You can rewrite your function with `reduce()` instead of `map()` (which probably should have been `forEach()` since you ignore the return)... that would avoid the named local variable.  But then I'm not sure how "pure" you need it to be.  You could write [either of these versions](https://tsplay.dev/wj5o6W) I guess, depending on whether mutations are strictly forbidden or allowable as long as they are hidden behind an abstraction barrier.

Comment: `reduce()` was the way to go... Thanks !